# Making a checkerboard pattern using CSS Selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of div elements that I'm currently displaying in two columns using CSS float. I would like to "alternate" the border color of these elements. I used alternate in quotes because what I really want is for the two divs in each "row" to alternate. Below is an example of what I want as my end state:

```
1blue   2green
3green  4blue
5blue   6green
7green  8blue
```

If I simply use nth-child(even) or nth-child(odd) I get the same color in each column vertically like:

```
1blue 2green
3blue 4green
5blue 6green
7blue 8green
```

The divs I want to target are located inside a WordPress loop so I don't have a lot of control over the markup (which is why I was hoping to use CSS nth-child). Unfortunately there isn't any markup that would allow me to target each individual "row".

Is there any kind of nth-child pattern that would allow me to do something like `blue[1], green[2],blue[2],etc` for an indefinite number of items?

I normally have a very good understanding of CSS but this is hurting my brain a little so thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you are making a simple checkerboard, so if you set every thing to green, you just need to override everything that needs to be blue. [`nth-child` can also accept a fomula that gives an `n` or multiple of `n` with an offset](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

As you have them numbered, note that in the right column you have `4` and `8` (next would be `12`), so you need every 4th element, and in the left you have `1` and `5` (next would be `9`), so you also need the 4th plus one (1 is technically `4*0+1`).

[There is a fiddle here that demos it](http://jsfiddle.net/tw7ncwka/), but the relevant code is:

```
/* Color everything green */
.checkerboard div {
    width:45%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}

/* Then color the appropriate divs blue */
.checkerboard div:nth-child(4n+1),
.checkerboard div:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

And gives:

[image: css checkerboard]

Answer (score 1):

I made a CSS checkerboard generator: https://codepen.io/RilDev/pen/mdXegEL

[image]

For a 4 by 4 checkerboard it would generate this code:

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 64px);
  }

  .square {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: black;
  }

  .square:nth-child(8n + 1),
  .square:nth-child(8n + 3),
  .square:nth-child(8n + 6),
  .square:nth-child(8n + 8) {
    background: white;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make blue 1 and green 2:

```
1:nth-of-type(2n+1){
   background-color: green;
}

2:nth-of-type(2n){
   background-color: blue;
}
```

and make sure the id's are set to 1 and 2 so it works

Answer (score -3):

You should use nth-child like this

```
div:nth-child(1){…your code here…}
div:nth-child(2){…your code here…}
div:nth-child(3){…your code here…}
div:nth-child(4){…your code here…}
div:nth-child(5){…your code here…}
div:nth-child(6){…your code here…}
div:nth-child(7){…your code here…}
div:nth-child(8){…your code here…}
```

By this you can do anything to each of your 8 div elements.

Comment: What happens if there is a 9th element, or 10th or 100th?

Comment: You should just pass the number into the bracket  to nth-child like this "div:nth-child(100).

Comment: So if I have 12, I'd need... `div:nth-child(9){}`, `div:nth-child(10)`, `div:nth-child(11)` and `div:nth-child(12)`?

Comment: Yes that's it. You understood.

Comment: So what if I need 16 divs...? Do I also need to write `div:nth-child(13)`, `div:nth-child(14)`, `div:nth-child(15)` and make sure I repliacte the rules correctly? Then what if after writing 15 different rules I decide to make it red instead of blue?

Comment: Then you should follow the way of lego storm above, it is easiest.

Comment: That lego storm fellow is one froody programmer.

Comment: Nth-child(n4) means it will go through the divs by 4. For example it will add style to 4th div and to 8th div after it, and to 12th div. As much divs as you have it will go by 4.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr *ahem*, I believe the correct adjective form is "hoopy." As in, "Zaphod's just this guy, you know? He's one hoopy frood."

Comment: Thanks Ahmadbaba46 but unfortunately it would not be maintainable by either my client or myself to target each of these divs individually because we expect to be continually adding content and creating more of them.

Comment: Just copy the code oc lego storm and create as many divs as you want to see how it work. You don't need to add style individually using it.