# How to 2 column alternating div background?

Tags: html, css

Hi Everyone at Stackoverflow

I've been looking around and can't seem to find the answer i was looking for how to do a correct alternating 2 column div background color as you can see here:

[image]
&:odd and &:even selectors don't seem to work for me, so obviously it has to be &:nth-child() something something, but my logical skills just isn't working for me.. anyone had similar experience and maybe can help me? :( the numbers on in the image indicate the order in which the div tags appear...

Comment: The odd/even/nth-child selectors should would for this case.  Can you paste your code?  A Fiddle would be best!

Comment: Hii Johns3n, are you generating these dives using a loop???

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808598/making-a-checkerboard-pattern-using-css-selectors

Comment: Mac: odd/even wouldn't work because 2 and 3 are the same colors actually, so it was nth-child but the math was appearently the thing that gave me headaches :(


Jacky Coogan Yes, they are will be generated by a loop


wellagain thank you wellagain... i didn't occure to me to search for checkerboard >< (English is not my primary language) But thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

1. `:nth-child(4n+2)` - 2, 6, 10, 14 ...
2. `:nth-child(4n+3)` - 3, 7, 11, 15 ...

```css
.wrap{    
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 0;    
}
.wrap > div{
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;  
    background: #fff;   
}
.wrap > div:nth-child(4n+2),
.wrap > div:nth-child(4n+3){    
    background: #F66C9B;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following css.

```
.row:nth-child(4n-1),
.row:nth-child(4n+2)
{
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sn9g69we/)

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward `nth-child` won't work here. Also, you've to apply some mathematics to achieve this kind of result.

The logic I applied here is basically using the multiple of number 4 to select `4` and `8` and then very next element by `4n+1`.

Here is the CSS:

```
.row:nth-child(4n),
.row:nth-child(4n+1)
{
    background: white;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f54Lhp6j/3/)**

Comment: Math really isn't my strong suit, so that's why It bit me really hard this problem i see :) Thanks for the help!